# How to propagating context through StructuredTaskScope by ScopedValue, by the way, how about the MDC ThreadContextMap in StructuredTaskScope?

Tags: java, thread-local, java-21, virtual-threads, scoped-value

In this case, i need to propagating some state like tracer/span or request context per request.
The jdk env is 21.0.1-preview.

I try to propagate any state between thread and virtual thread by a common way.

Also, the full implementation will be compatible with ThreadLocal scenarios
like:
[context-propagation]: ([https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation）](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation%EF%BC%89)
[TransmittableThreadLocal]: https://github.com/alibaba/transmittable-thread-local/blob/master/README-EN.md)

In jdk 21, Thread is defined as Platform Thread, and the following three scenarios are my targets this time around

1. virtual threads -> platform threads
2. platform threads -> virtual threads
3. virtual threads -> virtual threads

Below is my specific code and includes some key ideas without platform threads cases.

Like:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
static class PropagatingTaskDecorator implements TaskDecorator {


    public record Tracer(String traceId, String spanId, String parentId) {

    }

    private final ScopedValue[] keys;

    public PropagatingTaskDecorator(ScopedValue<?>... keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    static class ScopedValueMap {

        public static final ScopedValue<Tracer> TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE = ScopedValue.newInstance();
        private final Map<ScopedValue<?>, Object> bindingsSnapshot;

        public ScopedValueMap() {
            bindingsSnapshot = Maps.newHashMap();
            if (TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE.isBound()) {
                var latestTracer = TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE.get();
                bindingsSnapshot.put(TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE, new Tracer(latestTracer.traceId(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), latestTracer.spanId()));
            } else {
                bindingsSnapshot.put(TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE, new Tracer(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), null));
            }
        }

        /**
         * here is a function that can be used to capture the current bindings of a set of ScopedValues
         * @param scopedValue scopedValue
         * @param <T> T
         */
        <T> void put(ScopedValue<T> scopedValue) {
            if (scopedValue.isBound()) {
                bindingsSnapshot.put(scopedValue, scopedValue.get());
            }
        }

        <T> T get(ScopedValue<T> scopedValue) {
            if (bindingsSnapshot.containsKey(scopedValue)) {
                return (T) bindingsSnapshot.get(scopedValue);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(STR."ScopedValue not found: \{scopedValue}");
        }
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Runnable decorate(@Nonnull Runnable runnable) {
        // capture the current bindings of a set of ScopedValues
        var bindingsSnapshot = new ScopedValueMap();
        for (var key : keys) {
            bindingsSnapshot.put(key);
        }
        /*
         * Here's the key, propagating snapshot state between virtual threads via bindingsSnapshot,
         * which bypasses the StructuredTaskScope limitation.
         *
         * Also, the full implementation will be compatible with ThreadLocal scenarios
         * (like https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation or https://github.com/oldratlee/log4j2-ttl-thread-context-map/blob/ master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/ttl/log4j2/TtlThreadContextMap.java)
         *
         * In jdk 21, Thread is defined as Platform Thread, and the following three scenarios are my targets this time around
         * 1. virtual threads -> platform threads
         * 2. platform threads -> virtual threads
         * 3. virtual threads -> virtual threads
         */
        return () -> {
            ScopedValue.Carrier carrier = ScopedValue.where(TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE, bindingsSnapshot.get(TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE));
            for (var key : keys) {
                carrier = carrier.where(key, bindingsSnapshot.get(key));
            }
            carrier.run(runnable);
        };
    }
}

@Slf4j
class ServiceImpl {
    public void xxx() {
        try (var executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("pg-")) {
            executor.setVirtualThreads(true);
            var decorator = new PropagatingTaskDecorator();
            executor.setTaskDecorator(decorator);
            executor.setThreadFactory(Thread.ofVirtual().name("v-").factory());

            executor.submit(() -> {
                log.info("{}", xxx); // here log4j2 need print trace info by %X{traceId}
                                     // but how count MDC work for ScopedValue
                                     // up to now, i overwrite the ThreadContextMap and 
                                     // try to split virtual/platform thread for different
                                     // way.
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone do me a fovor ?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to fabulous SO and thank you for the interesting question!

First, from the standpoint of `ScopedValue` usage you code is, in my opinion, quite correct. I wasn't able to understand what are `bindingsSnapshot` variable and `ScopedValueMap` class in your code, but if you declare `TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE` constant like

```
private static final ScopedValue<String> TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE = ScopedValue.newInstance();
```

, create a `Carrier` with a value in `decorate` method, not in the `Runnable`

```
ScopedValue.Carrier carrier = ScopedValue.where(TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE, "Long live SO!");
```

, then upon the execution of the task you would be able to retrieve this value:

```
String value = TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE.get();
```

So, I believe, it fulfills your goal of propagating a state (`TRACER_SCOPED_VALUE`) from "a thread" (the one which executes `ServiceImpl.xxx`, Executor's `submit`, and Decorators' `decorate`) to "a virtual thread", started by Executor.

The following snippet demonstrates sharing a value between a thread that submits a task to an `Executor` and a thread that executes this task:

```
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskDecorator;

...

private static final ScopedValue<String> SCOPED_VALUE = ScopedValue.newInstance();

private static class ScopedValueDecorator implements TaskDecorator {

    public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
        final ScopedValue.Carrier carrier = ScopedValue.where(SCOPED_VALUE, "Long Live SO!"); 
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " maps " + carrier.get(SCOPED_VALUE));
        return () -> {
            carrier.run(runnable);
        };          
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("scope-value-")) {
    executor.setTaskDecorator(new ScopedValueDecorator());
    executor.submit(() -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " retrieves " + SCOPED_VALUE.get());
    });
}
```

}

Note that the usage of virtual threads is not required; `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, however, does not pool the threads and platform threads could be too expensive.

As for MDC, (`BasicMDCAdapter`, `LogbackMDCAdapter`) it uses `ThreadLocal`, not `ScopedValue` in a currently available latest version. `ThreadLocal` and `ScopedValue`, although targeting similar problem, are *technically* unrelated things. So, an answer to

> how count MDC work for ScopedValue up to now

is "MDS doesn't".

EDIT: It does not until you go ahead and implement [your own `MDCAdapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195317/2366397). An example of such implementation is discussed in [Logback: availability of MDCs in forks created inside a StructuredTaskScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142173/logback-availability-of-mdcs-in-forks-created-inside-a-structuredtaskscope/)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your careful answers ：） Based on your suggestions and questions, I have refined my question and added some code so that you can understand my goal better. Let me explain some of your questions about my code before the latest edition. Due to jdk21's concurrency domain limitations for ScopedValue, it is not automatically propagated across virtual threads, so the alternative is to use a binding snapshot to manually bind across virtual threads or platform threads in a AOP manner(decorator/aspect4j/spring-aop...).

Comment: If you want to have a mapping from `ScopeValue`s to `Tracer`s, then the updated example doesn't do this. There only one instance of `ScopeValue` is created (as static field). While it is possible to create one `ScopeValue` per  `Tracer`, this approach is discouraged. It is possible, instead, to create a single `ScopeValue` with a collection/map of `Tracer`s, but in this case it is not clear how to implement the logic of inspecting of bound status of `ScopeValue` . In general, lack of understanding of your intentions/detailed explanations prevents me from commenting further.

Comment: One note about the virtual nature of a thread in respect of `ScopeValue`. The latter does not require a thread which retrieves the value to be virtual; it can be an ordinary/platform thread. Therefore the three scenarios you described in your question are unrelated  to the usage of `ScopeValue`. Sure, famous example in `StructuredTaskScope` by default uses virtual threads in `scope.fork` and platform threads might be too expensive for the purpose, but full-blown thread pool `Executor` may come to rescue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Convert **Tracer** to **collection/map** in **ScopeValue** can be a good idea. With your suggestion, I'll make some more attempts to see if I can make some adjustments to the previous code

Comment: Thank you! I have placed a small POC of that idea into the GitHub repo at https://github.com/eager-zh/scoped-value-usage and started a discussion there in case you or anybody else will have some question or suggestions - your case is interesting, but here the discussion is becoming too lengthy and specific. 
Storing multiple Tracers under single ScopedVaLue seems to be straightforward, but, like I said above, I don't quite understand how and why do you plan to inspect bound status with `isBound` method and is it OK if it is done for a collection of Tracers, not for every Tracer individually.