# Utilizing Logging MDC with Virtual Threads

Tags: java, servlets, virtual-threads

In a typical servlet environment, each request gets its own thread. Adding logging MDC to generate a unique request ID to the request can be achieved with a simple servlet filter.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("requestId", requestId);
        MDC.put("requestId", requestId);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        MDC.remove("requestId");
    }
}
```

Logging configuration.

```
<Pattern>%d %-5level %X{requestId} [%t] %C{10}:%L %m%n</Pattern>
```

Sample logging.

```
2024-02-04 10:29:55,160 INFO  99cd4d64-5d7c-4577-a5d3-cb8d48d1dfd5 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] c.s.q.UserController:65 Deleteing user 'test'
2024-02-04 10:29:55,260 INFO  99cd4d64-5d7c-4577-a5d3-cb8d48d1dfd5 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] c.s.q.UserController:70 Successfully deleted user 'test'
```

With Virtual Threads in Java 21+, I'm under the impression a thread can automatically suspended a request while it's waiting on any IO and the thread can begin working on other requests. In this scenario it seems like the logging MDC can "bleed" into other request logs as the thread begins serving other requests. How can I work around this so I can continue to have a unique value added to each request's logging statements?

Comment: “Adding logging MDC to generate a unique request ID to the request can be achieved with a simple servlet filter.”  I feel the need to point out that Log4J may be in common use (despite its shoddy security), but it is in no way a standard part of a web application.  That aside, a Thread is still a Thread in Java.  Code and libraries that rely on Threads will continue to work as they always have.  The only difference is in their use of shared resources, and most of the time, even that will be transparent.

Comment: It is unclear from the context if the unique value in your case is `requestId` or `threadId`? Since requestId will not change based on the thread that handles the request within the server, logs can still be grouped based on them if need be.

Comment: @Naman, yes, _basically_ both uniquely identifies a request, but `MDCAdapter` opens the door to a usage of more sophisticated mechanisms: one of them is `InheritableThreadLocal`, another one - `ThreadLocal` transferring and third one, in the context of Loom, is `ScopedValue`.

Comment: @VGR The usage of MDC isn't log4j specific. I didn't include the import statements in my code snippet, but in this case MDC is coming from slf4j. I have verified that logback will include the requestId via MDC as well.

Answer (score 7):

If the MDC Adapter you use is the one that uses `ThreadLocal`, e.g. `LogbackMDCAdapter`, then the filter you posted will work fine for virtual threads as well as for platform threads. If your virtual thread would be suspended and then *continued* on another *Carrier* (platform) thread, then its `ThreadLocal`s would be correctly transferred (at least Project Loom so promises).

["Don't Cache Expensive Reusable Objects in Thread-Local Variables"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-68216B85-7B43-423E-91BA-11489B1ACA61) of Virtual Threads doc says:

> Virtual threads support thread-local variables just as platform threads do

However, the users of virtual threads are warned against excessive usage of `ThreadLocal`s on virtual threads (which could be very well understood as these `ThreadLocal`s have to be transferred between *Carrier* threads of our virtual thread - this is pretty rough picture of what is going on "under the hood").

Instead, Project Loom advises to use `ScopedValue`. However, in the scope of your question, 1) a usage of `ScopedValue` should be initiated at the point of virtual thread spawning, i.e. somewhere in Servlet Container (if Tomcat is used then it would be a Connector) and 2) a special `ScopedValue`-oriented `MDCAdapter` implementation should be used 3) `ScopedValue` is still a preview in Java 21. Some plans in that direction have been laid out in [How to propagating context through StructuredTaskScope by ScopedValue... how about the MDC ThreadContextMap in StructuredTaskScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716273/how-to-propagating-context-through-structuredtaskscope-by-scopedvalue-by-the-wa). It seems to me that, as `ScopedValue` is designed, the efforts should be applied at two levels: Servlet Container, where the virtual thread is spawned, and special `MDCAdapter` implementation. More on usage of `ScopedValue`s for MDC on [Logback: availability of MDCs in forks created inside a StructuredTaskScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142173/logback-availability-of-mdcs-in-forks-created-inside-a-structuredtaskscope/).